# Set action on complete of drag and drop interaction in Adobe Captivate

Tags: drag-and-drop, adobe-captivate

I am using the new drag and drop functionality in Adobe Captivate 6.1. I have created a simple drag and drop so that the user cannot drag an object to a wrong drop area. (The object will return to it's original position).

Once all the objects are dragged to their correct drop areas, I have selected the 'Auto submit' option.

How can I set an action to occur when the drag and drop interaction is complete? I would like to do either of the following:
a) Go to the next slide
b) Display a success message, and add a button for the user to 'continue' (go to next slide).

I have set 'Go to next slide' in the action pannel as the 'On success' action, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How this is done:**
In the Action pannel, select the 'infinite' checkbox. There are "On Success" and "On Failure" drop downs below this. I would advise that you save these settings IMMEDIATELY after making your interaction.

I have on many occasions set these to do what I would like, do some other work on the project, (set the size that images will shrink down to once dropped in the appropriate area) and these options will become inactive. I am not sure why this kept happening, so I called adobe support and had a screen share session. He couldn't find out why this was happening either, and every time it did I would just delete the interaction and start again.

So keep checking the action pannel after every move you make and save your work frequently to avoid running into this extremely frustrating bug.